# Making VPC default while creating thru AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have successfully created the VPC via AWS PHP SDK. However, I can't see anyways to make the VPC as default VPC for given region.

**Visual:**

[image]

---

When I use below code, all the VPC are defualt to **false**.

**Code to create VPC**

```
$result = $client->createVpc(array(
    'DryRun' => true || false,
    // CidrBlock is required
    'CidrBlock' => 'string',
    'InstanceTenancy' => 'string',
));
```

**Hope this may allow me to change but No**

```
$result = $client->modifyVpcAttribute(array(
    // VpcId is required
    'VpcId' => 'string',
    'EnableDnsSupport' => array(
        'Value' => true || false,
    ),
    'EnableDnsHostnames' => array(
        'Value' => true || false,
    ),
));
```

Any idea or thoughts how to set Vpc to default? I have check AWS-CLI as well it doesn't have the option to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Your account comes with a default VPC. That will remain the default VPC. (unless and of-course AWS technical support has some magic wand behind the curtains to make it happen.)